# JScrollBar programmatically

Tags: java, events

How can I move programmatically a `JScrollBar` based on amount of wheel mouse rotation?

Comment: it will handle automatically.

Comment: Yes but I want do it programmatically when a user interacts with another component (e.g. a JSlider...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use the `setValue` method of the JScrollBar to set the position of the scroll bar.

Alternatively you can use the methods of the Model behind the JScrollBar; example: `bar.getModel().setValue(position)`.

You can use the `getMinimum` and `getmaximum` methods of the JScrollBar (or from the Model) to check the valid values for `setValue`.

The Javadoc should help more: [JScrollBar](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollBar.html)

Answer (score 0):

> The type of scrolling that occurs,
>   either WHEEL_UNIT_SCROLL or
>   WHEEL_BLOCK_SCROLL, is platform
>   dependent. The amount that the mouse
>   wheel scrolls is also platform
>   dependent. Both the type and amount of
>   scrolling can be set via the mouse
>   control panel for the platform.control panel for the platform.

From [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mousewheellistener.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private void scrollToBottom() {
    int tamanio = scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().getMaximum();
    scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().getModel().setValue(tamanio);
}

private void scrollToTop() {    
    scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().getModel().setValue(0);
}

private void scrollToNext() {
    int posicion = scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().getModel().getValue(); 
    int altura = scrollPane.getHeight();
    scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().getModel().setValue(posicion+altura);
}

private void scrollToBack() {
    int posicion = scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().getModel().getValue(); 
    int altura = scrollPane.getHeight();
    scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().getModel().setValue(posicion-altura);
}
```